# SAS DO loop with SET statement

Tags: sas

Given two simple datasets A and B as follows

```
DATA A; INPUT X @@;
CARDS;
1 2 3 4
RUN;

DATA B; INPUT Y @@;
CARDS;
1 2
RUN;
```

I am trying to create two datasets named C and D, one using repeated SET and OUTPUT statements and another using DO loop.

```
DATA C;      
  SET B; 
  K=1; DO; SET A; OUTPUT; END;
  K=K+1; DO; SET A; OUTPUT; END;
  K=K+1; 
RUN;

DATA D;
  SET B; 
  DO K = 1 TO 2; 
    SET A; OUTPUT; 
  END; 
RUN;
```

I thought that C and D should be the same as the DO loop is supposed to be repeating those statements as shown in the DATA step for C, but it turns out that they are different.

```
Dataset C:
Obs    Y    K    X
 1     1    1    1
 2     1    2    1
 3     2    1    2
 4     2    2    2

Dataset D:
Obs    Y    K    X
 1     1    1    1
 2     1    2    2
 3     2    1    3
 4     2    2    4
```

Could someone please explain this?

Comment: Note that the DO/END blocks in the first data step are not doing anything.  You could remove the DO and END statements and that step will work exactly the same without them.

Answer (score 3):

The two `SET A` statements in the first data step are independent. So on each iteration of the data step they will both read the same observation. So it is as if you ran this step instead.

```
data c;
  set b;
  set a;
  do k=1 to 2; output; end;
run;
```

The `SET A` statement in the second data step will execute twice on the first iteration of the data step. So it will read two observations from `A` for each iteration of the data step.

If you really wanted to do a cross-join you would need to use `point=` option so that you could re-read one of the data sets.

```
data want ;
  set b ;
  do p=1 to nobs ;
    set a point=p nobs=nobs ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would it be possible to modify 'DATA C; ' such that it produces the same results as 'DATA D; '? The stated difference indicates that my understandings of how the DO loop operates could be incorrect.

Comment: You cannot make executing two distinct SET statements operate the same as executing one SET statement twice.  You could possible use two different POINT= pointer variables for the two different SET statements.

Answer (score 2):

Your Table B has two obs so your code will only do two iterations:

1. Every time you read a new observation K resets to 1, Solution: use `Retain` keyword.
2. When your current records is OBS 1 and you do an output, you will keep outputting the first row from each table, that's why you output the first and second rows twice from table A.

Debugging:

Iteration 1 current view:

```
Obs Table X
1    A    1
Obs Table Y k 
1    B    1 1
```

Output:

```
K=1; DO; SET A; OUTPUT; END;
Obs    Y    K    X
 1     1    1    1

K=K+1; DO; SET A; OUTPUT; END;
Obs    Y    K    X
2     1    2    1
```

Iteration 2 current view:

```
Obs Table X
2    A    2
Obs Table Y k 
2    B    2 1
```

Output:

```
K=1; DO; SET A; OUTPUT; END;
Obs    Y    K    X
 3     2    1    2

K=K+1; DO; SET A; OUTPUT; END;
Obs    Y    K    X
4     2    2    2
```